# Mapping of entity and model in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, nopcommerce

I am mapping the following Entity and Model using NopCommerce 3.0

**Entity**

```
public partial class Package : BaseEntity
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int PackageNumber { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }
    }
```

**Model**

```
[Validator(typeof(PackageValidator))]
    public class PackageModel
    {
        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Packages.Fields.ProductID")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Packages.Fields.Quantity")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Packages.Fields.PackageNumber")]
        public int PackageNumber { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Packages.Fields.Weight")]
        //[AllowHtml]
        public string Weight { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Packages.Fields.DisplayOrder")]
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Packages.Fields.Published")]
        public bool Published { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my **Mapper class**

```
public partial class PackageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Package>
    {
        public PackageMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Package");
            this.HasKey(m => m.Id);
            this.Property(m => m.ProductID);
            this.Property(m => m.Quantity);
            this.Property(m => m.PackageNumber);
            this.Property(m => m.Weight);
            this.Property(m => m.DisplayOrder);
            this.Property(m => m.Published);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the following exception

**[AutoMapperMappingException: Trying to map Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.Package to Nop.Admin.Models.Catalog.PackageModel.
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.]
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +382**

I am new to Asp.net MVC. Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your exception said that there is no proper Automapper map between Package and PackageModel. May be you should write this map in your code?

Comment: I have added mapper code, please check

Comment: it is mapping to database. But exception is about automapper map from your entity to your packagemodel. Try to google Automapper for additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need configuation code. It will be something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Package , PackageModel>();
```

and probably reverse, if you are mapping in both directions.

Comment: Did you do also reverse mapping, and are you sure that this part of code is invoked before you are trying to do mapping?

Comment: yes.., well I had also tried your method.. it resolves this issue, now no exception is occurring but the after mapping the data is lost when model is mapped into an entity